# Fixed width page

Tags: css, size, zooming, fixed-width

URL: http://vixenology.com/

At the standard zoom level the entire blog is aligned left and there is this huge no mans land to the right. How can I cut the size of the page down so the blog is centered at all zoom levels?

Ive tried some simple css and cant seem to figure it out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for:

```
.main-width { margin: 0px auto; }
```

Comment: .main-width { margin: 0px auto; }     <-This worked perfectly for the text but now if you zoom out the background image shifts left..  THANKS

Answer (score 4):

Hmm. How about putting your main content in a div and centering that with:

```
margin: 0 auto;
width: /* the width of your content */
```

You'd have to rearrange your html markup though; I tried doing this, but it cut off your background. You'll have to take your background-image out of the div you want to center and put it around that div. If that makes sense.. Something like:

```
<body>
   <div id="bg"><!-- give this id the background-image in css -->
      <div id="maincontent">
         <!-- this div contains all your content, everything that needs centering -->
      </div>
   </div
</body>
```

Then in your css:

```
#bg { background-image: /* blabla */ }
#maincontent { margin: 0 auto; width: /* width, as stated above */ }
```

Something like that.

Answer (score 0):

give the wrapping div a fixed width and give it a margin: 0 auto